# Why does C# Type.GetProperty() behave differently for interfaces than for base classes?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Why doesn't `Type.GetProperty(string)` get a property from a base interface if the type is an interface? For example, the following code prints:

```
System.String X
null
System.String X
System.String X
```

which seems inconsistent:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(I1).GetProperty("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(I2).GetProperty("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(C1).GetProperty("X"));
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(C2).GetProperty("X"));;
}

public interface I1 { string X { get; } }

public interface I2 : I1 { }

public class C1 { public string X { get { return "x"; } } }

public class C2 : C1 { }
```

**EDIT:** another aspect of the runtime that supports Cole's answer is the following:

```
public class C : I2 {
    // not allowed: the error is
    // 'I2.X' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface
    string I2.X { get; set; }

    // allowed
    string I1.X { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with it being a class or an interface. X is private in one and public in the other.

Comment: Interfaces can be implemented explicitly ('hiding' the methods on the implementing class), whereas public properties on a class are always visible.  You'll see the same behavior if you explicitly implement I1 on C1, whereas if you implement it implicitly, the GetProperty will find it.

Comment: @CoryNelson all interface properties are public. Or are you saying that I2 explicitly implements I1 and thus it's I1 methods are private? If that's true, then why can you access X via an instance of I2 without a cast?

Comment: @DanBryant: but, if you implement I1 explicitly on C1, you wont be able to call new C1().X. However, if you implement I2 non-explicitly on C1 and you have a variable I2 i2 = new C1(), you can call i2.X. That would suggest that this is not a matter of I2 explicitly implementing I1, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion You are correct. Temporary insanity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that class inheritance is not the same as interface implementation.

A derived class and its base class have an **is-a** relationship.  If `D : B` then `D` **is a** `B`.  If `B` has a property, then `D` will by definition also have that same property, because that's what that relationship *means*; the "substance" of `D` is in some sense altered by its relationship to `B`.

Interfaces provide no implementation, so when you say `ID : IB`, you're not really saying `ID` **is a** `IB` in the same way that you do with classes.  What would that even mean?  `ID` and `IB` aren't *things*; they're *agreements*.  There's nothing there to alter.  Instead, you're saying "a class which implements `ID` must also provide an implementation for `IB`."

The fact that `ID` derives from `IB` doesn't change `ID` because it has no substance to change.  It just means that any class which promises to fulfill the contract specified by `ID` must also be prepared to adhere to an additional set of requirements.

Bearing this in mind, if `IB` provides a property `X`, the proper answer to "does `ID` have a property `X`?" is *no*.  `ID` requires you to also implement `IB`, which *does* have a property `X`, but it does not itself have a property `X`.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but can you ground it in either some kind of C# documentation or a description of how classes and interfaces differ under the hood? Can you point out other behavior in the reflection API that is consistent with this distinction (other than the obvious parallel of GetMethod). For example, GetInterfaces() works equivalently for classes and interfaces.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion: As you note, your question is about the behaviour of the Reflection library. There is no requirement whatsoever that the rules of Reflection be the same as the rules of C#, or VB, or F#, or any other managed language. The C# specification has nothing to say on the subject of what Reflection should do; the documentation you should be looking for is the documentation of the Reflection library.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion:  I would argue that `GetProperty()` _also_ works equivalently for classes and interfaces.  It returns properties which are defined on the type.  In `ID : IB` with `X` on `IB`, the semantics of interface implementation mean that `X` is not defined on `ID`.  As for documentation, I'm afraid I don't know of any.  I'm just trying to explain the behavior you're seeing based on my understanding of the semantics of inheritance as opposed to those of implementation.